# Каким образом в Sass работают псевдоклассы?

Tags: css, вёрстка, sass, scss

В документе main.sass не могу разобраться каким образом применить псевдокласс `first-child` или `nth-child`.

`&:hover, active, focus` и др. прекрасно применяются.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы правильно написали, для `hover`, `focus` и `active`.

Стили для псевдоклассов работают также:

```
div
  position: relative
  &:before
    content: 'la-la-la'
```

Единственное, для `child` элементов нужно явно показать родителя:

```
.wrapper .block
  position: relative
  &:first-child
    display: none
```